# How to configure CvSVM for image classification in OpenCV and C++

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, libsvm

i am developing a handwritten character recognition system using OpenCV LibSVM. i have extracted 14 features for the feature vector including Hu moments, affine invariant moments, numbers of corners etc. For each character, i use 5 samples( for letter "A", there 5 types of A's). I know 5 samples is not enough, but at the moments i have only 5 samples for each character.

I use the basic LINEAR SVM example in opencv documentation. My problem is, can i use that documentation example as it is, for my purpose. I have read about OCR systems that use multi- class SVMs. Do i need such Multi-Class SVM for my application. I do not understand about this. Please can someone explain ? Here is my code.

i have 180 samples of digits and English capital letters  and for one sample there are 14 features.

```
float labels[180][1] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, ,,,,, -> 180.0};
Mat matlabesls(180,1, CV_32FC1, labels);

Mat mattrainingDataMat(180, 14, CV_32FC1, ifarr_readtrainingdata);
CvSVMParams params;

params.svm_type    = CvSVM::C_SVC;
params.kernel_type = CvSVM::LINEAR;
params.term_crit   = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 1e-6);

CvSVM SVM;
SVM.train(mattrainingDataMat,matlabesls,Mat(),Mat(),params);

Mat matinput(1,14,CV_32FC1,ifarr_testarray);
is_recognizedcharacter= SVM.predict(matinput);

return is_recognizedcharacter;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The setup of your labels is incorrect. You have defined 180 unique labels, but you only have 26 classes of data. Labels should be 180 in lengeth but it should only contain the values 1..26 (any 26 distinct values will do) in an order that is in accord with the order of characters in mattrainingDataMat.

You will need more like 5000 samples of each letter rather than just 5. You could start with the MNIST hand-writen digits data set until you have proper data.

Your code seems to training an svm to just recognize 1 character. You shouldn't do it like that because it can take a *long* time to train an svm. You should train the svm separately and save the model so it can be reused without have to retrain everytime.

My understanding is that the svm code in OpenCV is based on an *old* version of Libsvm. So I just use the latest vesion of libsvm directly rather the OpenCV version.

Also, for your case you will almost surely get much better accurary with an RBF kernel than the linear kernel (although linear is easier to train). It seems you have 26 classes so of course you need a multiclass SVM (which is really just many binary SVMs) - Libsvm handles the multiclass issue for you.

Comment: hi thank you very much for considering my question. i change the code as follows. i have 36 classes(26 letters, 10 digits). At the moment i  use only 5 samples(until i get clear idea). for one class there are 5 samples and for one sample there are 14 features. then for one class there are 70 features(5 * 14). is that what you mean ?? plz help ..                                                       'float labels[36][1] = {1.0, 2.0, ... -> 36.0};                                        
Mat matlabesls(36,1, CV_32FC1, labels)
Mat mattrainingDataMat(36, 70, CV_32FC1, ifarr_readtrainingdata);'

Comment: If your data consisted of the features for 3 examples of 'A', 2 of 'C' and 3 of '5' (in that order), then your labels would be 'float labels[7][1] ={11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 13.0,13,0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0} assuming 0.0..9.0 are used to label '0' to '9' and 11.0..35.0 are used to label 'A'..'Z'.  If the order of your data was jumbled up, the labels would need to be jubled up to match. The labels are telling the SVM what each data item is a sample of.

Comment: thank you very much, i understand about labeling. can you tell me about where the multiclass SVM in here. i feel, as you said there are 3 11.0's , 2 13.0's ... etc. is that called as MultiClass SVM ??

Comment: If you only had 2 labels, say 0 and 1, or -1 and 1, then it would be a binary svm. If you supply more than 2 different values then linsvm (which opencv uses) *automatically* trains many binary svms and combines the results so you have a multiclass classifier. The actual svm algorithm is binary in nature, it just looks for a hyperplane that will separate your data into two sets (ideally with all the labels in each set the same).  If your data consisted of just two'A's and three 'C's you would have 'float labels[5][1] ={11.0, 11.0, 13.0,13.0 13.0} and that will give you a binary svm.

Comment: @user2151446- k then i will configure my code and observe the output. Thank you very much for your help and your effort in my question.HND